# crawler failed with internal issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am running crawler on S3 bucket its sizes is 2gb.Whenever I try to run crawler its get failed with Internal Service Exception

Any resolution for this ?.I'm stuck here

I have also used this link but didnt help alot https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-crawler-internal-service-exception/?nc1=h_ls

Need your suggestion

```
2021-08-09T13:56:05.984+02:00   [60c350cc-eab6-4510-aa4a-cdee286d819a] ERROR : Internal Service Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me a while ago, I also checked the documentation you shared but it didn't help me either, in my case the scenario was different, in short when I ran the crawler for the first time everything worked fine, after that I applied a modification to the schema from one of the tables obtained, this change involved what a partition is, days later I ran it again and received that error, to fix it I did the following:

- I ran it again, the error persisted
- I fetched the changed table
- Then I deleted only that table
- I ran the crawler again
- Finally the result was successful

I don't remember having read this scenario around, but I had to face it, in this case I caused it myself as you noticed, I hope it helps you, successes